# How to call a C function that simply prints out a statement depending on the parameter

Tags: c, function, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int guessGame(int guessed_num){
    int counter = 0;
    int random_num = 0;

 while(1)
    {
        counter++;
        if (guessed_num == random_num)
        {
            printf("Correct! That's the number.\n", counter);
            break;
        }

        if (guessed_num < random_num)
            printf("Too low. Guess again.\n");

        if (guessed_num > random_num)
            printf("Too high. Guess again.\n");

    }

}

int main(){

int guessed_num = 0;


srand(time(NULL));
int random_num = rand() % 50 + 1;

printf("I have a number between 1-50.\n");
printf("Can you guess what it is?\n");
printf("Enter your initial guess.\n");

        scanf("%d", &guessed_num);
        printf("%d\n" ,guessGame(guessed_num));


return 0;
}
```

So i have to make a guessing game where the user has to correctly guess a randomly created integer. The thing is, I have to use a function to run the actual guessing game. I'm stuck because I don't know how to properly call my function. I know for a fact my printf statement in my main function is not the proper way to do it.

Comment: Why do you need a while loop in guessGame()?  As I understand from your question, you want to just print out the guess status (too low, too high, etc.) on the basis of what the user has entered once, correct?

Comment: yes sir you are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you just want to print out the guess status (too high, too low, etc.) depending upon the single parameter the user enters, it is not necessary for you to use the while loop within your function.  The below code will help:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<time.h>

int random_num;
void guessGame(int guessed_num){


if (guessed_num == random_num)
    printf("Correct! That's the number.\n", guessed_num);
else
    if (guessed_num < random_num)
        printf("Too low. Guess again.\n");
    else
        printf("Too high. Guess again.\n");
}

int main(){

int guessed_num = 0;
srand(time(NULL));
random_num = rand() % 50 + 1;

printf("I have a number between 1-50.\n");
printf("Can you guess what it is?\n");
while(1){
printf("Enter your initial guess.\n");

    scanf("%d", &guessed_num);
    guessGame(guessed_num);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: sorry for not clarifying earlier but how do I keep the code running until the user correctly guesses the random number?

Comment: Edited the code.  It will keep running till the user correctly guesses the random number.

Comment: but the thing is, I create a random number in the MAIN function but that random number doesn't carry on into my guessGame function. It's initialized as 0 in the function. I removed that, but how do I carry that random value into the function. I tried creating a random number inside the function but that won't work because every time a new iteration is run, a new random value is created. How do i fix this?

Comment: To fix this, I have changed the declaration of the random_num variable.  It is global now.  If the answer is helpful, then please accept it.

Comment: i need one last bit of help. After guessing the random number correctly, if I want to give the user the option to play the game again, how would i go about doing so? Would I do that in the guessGame function? or in the main function?

Comment: Even after the random number is correctly guessed, the user still has the option to go ahead and enter other numbers.  If you want that a new random number should be generated and the game should start all over again, then it will require significant changes in the code (and should be a new question).  To give you a pointer, you can make use of a do-while loop.

Comment: okay, i will post this as a separate question. Can you please help me then?